# SQL Server Cannot see tables in Object Browser where Login = db_owner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

A colleague is trying access a particular SQL Server over a remote link. He can login to the server (via SSMS) with the SQL Server credentials I supplied, but although he can view tables/etc in the Object Browser for one database, he can't view them in another.

The login I provided was added to the db_owner role for both databases, and so I expected access to be the same.

If I login locally, from a neighbouring server using the same login, I can see everything fine. An obvious difference here is that I am inside the same network and am accessing the server via NETBIOS name. [It occurs to me that I should try using IP address, as he does]

I've tried creating an alternate user with the same permission - no improvement, as expected.

However, if he creates a new query window, he can access both databases and run queries against them.

Can anyone suggest why he might be struggling to see the expected objects in SSMS?

Comment: Is he opening the connection by double-clicking an instance in the Registered Servers window or using the Connect drop-down / button in Object Browser?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure at this moment - I've already asked him to try using the Connect drop-down to confirm that the Object Browser is connected as the same user.

Comment: I've just spoken to my colleague - he tries to explicitly connect via Object Browser and it makes no difference. However, I've manage to connect into the same system with the same user from a different remote site without any problems at all. Confusing.